# Intall Ubuntu 18.04 on old Mac

Tags: macosx

I have been trying to install Ubuntu 18.04 on my old 24" Mac. It runs OSX 10.6.8 and can't be upgraded. I can't run Etcher since it requires OSX 10.9 or later. I tried the instructions outlined [here](https://itsfoss.com/create-bootable-ubuntu-usb-drive-mac-os/) but EFI never recognizes the drive even though the transfer is successful. 
Any ideas?

Specs:

- 24" iMac
- 2.16 GHz Intel Core 2 Duo
- 3GB 667 MHz DDR2 SDRAM

Answer (score 0):

Use bootcamp, runs like breeze.
Bootcamp use "Refind" or "Refit" boot manager and this can replace GRUB. 
I run Mint Cinnamon with Docky and Wine. But you can use Ubuntu and the MacOS widgets and icons and most believe I run MacOS. Treat your old buddy and workhorse with the best, and never change a winning horse...